# Selenium C# How do I call a method from another class both classes inherit from a base class

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am having trouble seeing the methods from one of the class.
I have created a MobileLoginPage class and I want to click the Menu button.
I noticed there is already a method defined to click the Menu button from a class called MobileNavigationPage.  The method is called ClickMenuNavigation

As this method already exists I should be able to call it from my MobileLoginPage class.  Avoid duplicating code.
I am not able to call it, when i write the code MobileNavigationLogin.
no methods show up.
I even tried to call the locator element by defining a method (getMenuNavigationElement) to return the locator.  I cannot see this locator from LoginPage class.

The class has been instantiated in the BasePage class, I do not know why I cannot see it's methods.

My code snippet is:

The BasePage is and all of our classes are instantiated here:

```
public class BasePage : SpecflowBaseTest

{
    internal MobileNavigationPage MobileNavigationPage => new 
    MobileNavigationPage(Browser);
    internal MobileLoginPage MobileLoginPage => new 
    MobileLoginPage(Browser);
}
```

The MobileNavigationPage is:

```
public void MobilenavigationPage : BasePage
{
    #region Elements

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "MobileMenuNavigation")]
    private IWebElement MenuButton {get; set;}

    #endregion

    #region Actions

    private void ClickMenuNavigation()
    {
        Actions.Click.Element(Browser, MenuButton);

    }

    private IWebElement getMenuNavigationElement()
    {
        return MenuButton;
    }

    #endregion 
}
```

The MobileLoginPage is:

```
public class MobileLoginPage : BasePage
{
    # region Actions

    public void ClickBrandFromMenuNavigation{}
    {
        // I want to call ClickMenuNavigation() from here                   
    }

    #endregion
}
```

From LoginPage class how do I call the method which is defined in MobileNavigationPage?

Answer (score 1):

The method is `private` which means it can only be used within a `MobilenavigationPage`.

You can make it `public` though, and then it will show up --

```
public void ClickBrandFromMenuNavigation()
{
    base.MobileNavigationPage.ClickMenuNavigation();                   
}
```

Comment: I have tried making it public and tried with protected also.  It still does not show up

Comment: ah, I have not tried with base.MobileNavigationPage.  I will try with this

Comment: sorry, that still does not work.  If i type base.  It does not see MobileNavigationPage.  I made the method public

Comment: Is the `BasePage` in the same assembly? Try making its properties `public` (or at least `protected`)  too.